# Permission for read file content google drive rest api v3 in node.js

Tags: node.js, google-drive-api, google-apis-explorer

I want to read a content of a file which is shared with me on google drive. My scope is: `SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'];` which is should give access to everything.
I tried [this tutorial](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/nodejs) and it worked, but when I changed the "listFiles" method to do downloading, I got the following error message:

"Error: The user has not granted the app xxxx read access to the file xxxx"

I also tried with a file id from "my drive" but I got the same error.

That is what I tried in the listFiles method:

```
var service = google.drive('v3');
    var fileId = 'XXXXXXXXXX';
    var dest = fs.createWriteStream('./calendar.csv');
    service.files.get({
        auth: auth,
        fileId: fileId,
        mimeType: "text/csv", //also tried to leave this line
        alt: "media"
    })
        .on('end', function() {
            console.log('Done');
        })
        .on('error', function(err) {
            console.log('Error during download', err);
        })
        .pipe(dest);
```

I also made a sheet from the csv file, and tried to open it with the following request:

```
service.files.export({
        auth: auth,
        fileId: fileId,
        mimeType: "text/csv"
    })
```

But it threw an "Insufficient Permission" error. It is weird because it worked directly from [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/export)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, the solution was easy but not so obvious.

I needed to delete and create again my credential file with the access and refresh tokens. I used different SCOPES at first.